How to delete the data branch of sensor devices in Apache IoTDB?
How can I delete the existing sensor branch in Apache IoTDB? When I imported the data from the cvs file to IoTDB server, since I write the data type incorrectly, now the data cannot be written into IoTDB. I checked the official guide and did not find any code example to specifically delete the device branch (seems like all the examples are for delete database). Are there any command alternatives for my scenario, or I need to generate delete database?

delete device cannot be used in Apache IoTDB. You can use delete database command to delete the entire database and import your data again with the new data type.
